# How to implement Paypal express checkout to get an IPN message?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I tried to implement the Paypal express checkout but I found a problem. I don't know how to implement the IPN correctly. Here is my form code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

                <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@mydomain.com">

                <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />

                <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Payment order" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value=7 />
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite/checkout/paypal_ipn" />


                <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

            </form>
```

As I use CodeIgniter, I create a function in my Controller to handle the response from Paypal. Here is the code:

```
function paypal_ipn() {
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    // Assign payment notification values to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    // Build the required acknowledgement message out of the notification just received
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // Add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to beginning of the acknowledgement

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode these values
        $req .= "&$key=$value";                   // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
    }

    // Set up the acknowledgement request headers
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";                    // HTTP POST request
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    // Send the HTTP POST request back to PayPal for validation
    fputs($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) {                     // While not EOF
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);               // Get the acknowledgement response
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  // Response contains VERIFIED - process notification

            echo "VERIVIED";
        } else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) { //Response contains INVALID - reject notification
            // Authentication protocol is complete - begin error handling

            echo "INVALID";
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);  // Close the file
}
```

I expected that after the buyer completed the payment in Paypal, it will be redirected to the notify_url I stated in the form and I get the message if it's VERIFIED or INVALID. But the fact is it stayed in the Paypal' "thank you" page.

What have I done wrong with the code so I couldn't get the notification.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how IPN works, IPN is asynchronous and is independent of the user.

Customer flow:

Your site's cart -> Paypal payment -> Paypal thank you OR Redirect to your order complete

IPN flow:

Waits for a transaction -> POSTS data to your url -> Your site verifies data -> Insert/Update order in DB

Comment: thanks for your answer. but then how do I know that the IPN message arrived to my url?

Comment: @Abaij your URL waits for a POST from Paypal, then it has to be POST it back to Paypal with a VERIFY, it waits for a VALID/INVALID reponse from Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

@Abaij - Add a logger to your IPN consumer code which writes a status message to a local file. Make sure its the first line of code in your IPN consumer code so it isn't missed should an exception get thrown before hand. 
Make sure your site has write access to the drive\folder where the logger intends too write.
Use the IPN simulator too send a test IPN too your site and see if a log is written. If you get a log then you have confirmation the consumer is being hit. If this is the case then you need too look further into whether you verification back too PayPal is working as expected. If you do not get a Log file then check Your site Port 80 is visible from the outside world.

Br